# CelesTrak is now a 501(c)(3) non-profit and redirects from .com to .org, should old posts be edited "à la bot"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, hyperlinks

Celestrak (T. Kelso) has sent out a notification including the following:

> Now that CelesTrak is a non-profit, we have been redirecting all traffic going to other CelesTrak domains (e.g., .com, .net, .space) to celestrak.org (not [www.celestrak.org](http://www.celestrak.org)). If your software does not handle the standard HTTP 301 response (Moved Permanently), you should change any references to other CelesTrak domains (typically celestrak.com or [www.celestrak.com](http://www.celestrak.com)) to celestrak.org. While using HTTPS is not required, it is highly recommended, to prevent potential future issues.

A quick check showed that most links to Celestrak in Space SE posts are of the `.com` variety. I found [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34060/12102) a link to the unsecured `http://celestrak.com/` and while it redirected to `.org` it was to the unsecured url.

I see two separate issues

1. we have links to unsecured versions of sites that have secured versions
2. we have (lots of) links that will always have to be redirected.

From time to time carefully written SE bots will peruse sites and make edits to address systemic issues. I wonder if either one of these warrants such attention?

Comment: [191 links](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22celestrak.com%22) in the network, [147 on Space.SE](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22celestrak.com%22). It's a simple find & replace, so [the Community bot can do it without bumping posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314169/295232), but I'm not sure if staff is willing to do so for links that aren't broken yet. (Well, they did for the network's HTTP -> HTTPS switch.) Mods can tag this [tag:status-review] to have staff have a look.

Comment: @Glorfindel Agreed, and done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We've replaced all of these URLs across the network. `celestrak.com` or `www.celestrak.com` links now point to `https://celestrak.org`. If we've missed anything, please let us know :)

Comment: Thanks and welcome to space! :-)

Comment: @uhoh https://youtu.be/MAW2lygZC_4